# Why spring-data repeat some post-processors

Tags: spring, spring-data

Spring framework already registers `BeanPostProcessor` which do wrap the Proxy object by dozens of Advice including `TransactionInterceptor` and `PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor`.

But I noticed also, the spring-data module explicitly adds `TransactionInterceptor` and `PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor` to the proxy advice list as in `RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport#createRepositoryFactory`

So what special in `RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport` to explicitly add this two Advice and not just let them added by the framework BPPs (`PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor` and `DefaultAdvisorAutoProxyCreator` for persistence exception translation and transaction synchronization respectively)?

Comment: Because there is no guarantee that the user registers those things by proper configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is related to the fact that, Repository interfaces needn't be annotated by `@Repository` and hence not being registered into the container by the `componentScan` of the `applicationContext`. and hence will not be bean-post-processed.

And hence the definition of `EnableJpaRepositories` is the following:

```
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Inherited
@Import(JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.class)
public @interface EnableJpaRepositories {
```

So, the `@EnableJpaRepositories` do the work by using `JpaRepositoriesRegistrar` 
which delegating the registration of repository interfaces to `RepositoryConfigurationDelegate#registerRepositoriesIn`.

And in such case, the manual registration of ExceptionTranslator Advice and Transaction Advice is required.